# extern struct array error: array type has incomplete element type

Tags: c, struct, typedef, extern

I have 3 files: `main.c`, `def.c`, `def.h`. Both `.c` files include `def.h`. 
All the files are in the same directory.
My compiler is **gcc version 4.9.2**.

In **def.h**:

```
struct _info {
    int a;
};
```

In **def.c**:

```
#include "def.h"
struct _info info[] = {};
```

And in **main.c**:

```
#include "def.h"
extern struct _info info[];
```

When I build `def.c` as an object file and then build with `main.c` like:

```
gcc -c def.c
gcc main.c def.o
```

And I got an error message: **array type has incomplete element type**

---

If I use `typedef` to define `struct _info` as `INFO` like:

```
typedef struct _info INFO;
```

And replace `struct _info` with `INFO` in `.c` files.
Compile ok then.

But **why** and **what** does `typedef` do?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Sounds like a compiler bug. What's your compiler and its version?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. How are you compiling?

Comment: just asking if all files are in same path

Comment: Just so you know, identifier in the global or tag namespace that begin with `_` are reserved by the implementation. Avoid those.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, thank you. It is just an example.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Even I compiled with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes`

Comment: @VikashKesarwani ,iBug I tried to reproduce them with new files and  different naming. The newer compiled ok. How strange! I think it is not the problem with naming. There must be something else I have not noticed.

Comment: typedef _info INFO is different from _info[ ]. The problem here is that you are declaring an array of structure with unknown length. Define how many instances of that struct you want like this: struct _info info[2]. Now the compiler knows how much memory to allocate.

Comment: Your question is "why and what does typedef do?" Here is the answer: typedef is an alias for the tag. In C, tag is the name of the variable that is associated with the structure, if the tag is related to the structure. For example, in your structure, _info is a tag. I agree with all comments above, especially about the array size. Please study this, and much will be reviled to you: https://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4024450/Tag-vs-Type-Names

Comment: @Hairi No, I am sorry. Even if I defined struct like you said `struct _info info[2];`, I still get the error message.

Comment: `struct _info info[] = {};` is an error in Standard C, there must be at least one initializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everybody's help. This question end up with a misspelling in `main.c`.
Something like:

`extern struct _infoo info[];`

When `typedef` replace them, all work fine definitely.

Comment: IMO this is a good reason to use typedef for structs; as then a typo gives a more obvious compilation error